# Mirroring websites - 403 Forbidden with user agent strings

Tags: wget, mirroring, httrack

I'm working on an application to mirror US university academic catalogs.  To do this, I have a cluster of Celery workers that use `wget` or [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to mirror the content, styles and scripts, then upload to our S3 bucket.

For a small number of university sites, I've been encountering a 403 - Forbidden error using wget/httrack with a Windows Chrome user agent string.  However, I'm able to load the web page in the browser.

I originally thought user agent and referer were the issue here, so I set them to Chrome 50 user agent and google.com, respectively.  However, I'm still encountering the issue.  However, if I use the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library with all these URLs, I get HTTP 200 responses.

I've ensured cookies are used, so I'm at a loss. Is there any reason why `requests` would work but `wget`/`httrack` not?

Comment: Just curious - have you thrown a simple proxy in the middle to see the differences in the requests the various tools are generating?

Comment: Hmm... no I haven't.  Now that you mention it, I can try it with an internal website and check the logs.

Comment: I bet there is some extra or missing header you'll find among the various methods you are trying.